# CakePHP 4 - access private property to determine whether a file has successfully uploaded

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP 4.x the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#uploaded-files) show how you can move an uploaded file as follows:

```
$files = $request->getUploadedFiles();

// Move the file.
$files[0]->moveTo($targetPath);
```

This works in terms of moving the uploaded file to wherever `$targetPath` is specified as.

But - how do you determine whether this was actually successful? After looking at the framework code this uses `Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile` which contains the `moveTo()` (https://github.com/laminas/laminas-diactoros/blob/2.10.x/src/UploadedFile.php#L162)  function. That function can throw errors, e.g.

```
throw Exception\UploadedFileErrorException::dueToStreamUploadError(
    self::ERROR_MESSAGES[$this->error]
);
```

The end of the function (if no errors get thrown) contains:

```
$this->moved = true;
```

The function's return type is `void`.

`$moved` is a private property of this class and there doesn't seem to be any function that allows you to "get" the value of `$moved` outside that class.

So how do you determine whether or not this actually succeed? Or do you just assume if it doesn't thrown an error it *has* succeeded?

It seems strange because PHP's native `move_uploaded_file` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) returns boolean, which is what you'd expect since you'd probably want to know whether uploading a file has actually worked successfully or otherwise.

What's stranger is that when I debug `$files` in the CakePHP application:

```
$files[0]->moveTo($destinationFile);
debug($files); 
die;
```

It shows a private property for "moved" which is `true`:

```
object(Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile) id:0 {
    // ...
    private moved => true
    private size => (int) 45578
    private stream => object(Laminas\Diactoros\Stream) id:1 { }
}
```

But because that's a private property I can't access it in my application, e.g.

```
debug($files[0]->moved);
```

results in:

> Cannot access private property Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile::$moved

In the above case I have manually checked that the file got moved to the correct location on my filesystem. But I can't determine that via my code, it seems.

Comment: Well the fact that it did _not_ throw any exceptions tells you it was successful, no?

Comment: @CBroe ok. So the solution is to use a `try...catch` block on `->moveTo...`? If it throws an exception handle that there, and if not then it has uploaded? Sorry I'm coming at this from years of using PHP's `move_uploaded_file` which has a boolean return type for this operation.

Comment: Yes, that would be the general way.